# How do I dynamically make a function in python?

Tags: performance, abstract-syntax-tree, python-3.8

I have a computer generated AST in python. I interpret this AST 2000 times, but this is slow. Moreover, this AST changes during runtime, and it's not known before compile time. I can codegen my AST to a valid python string, but I don't know how to execute it. To give a conceptual overview, this is what I have now:

```
def exec(AST):
   {local variables}
   {interpret AST over local variables 2000 times}
```

I would like:

```
def exec(AST):
  {local variables}
  new_fn = make_lambda(to_python_string(AST))
  {iterate new_fn over local variables 2000 times}
```

Note: different calls to `exec` will have totally new unknown AST that was constructed at runtime.
My current bottleneck is in the AST interpretation, and my hope is that dynamic function generation will make it faster.

Comment: "new_fn = make_lambda(to_python_string(AST))"
You answered your own question, writ e a function that returns a function 
and use this in the loop.

Comment: How do I write a function from a string during runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So python3.8 does have an `exec` command that takes a string, and executes it. There are some caveats if your generated function calls local variables.

This works:

```
def exec(AST):
  {local variables}
  exec("def new_fn():\n" + to_python_string(AST), globals())
  {iterate new_fn over local variables 2000 times}
```

This is blazingly faster than interpreting the AST.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
def fun1():
    return 5


def fun2():
    return 7


def make_lambda(x):
    if x == 1:
        return fun1
    else:
        return fun2

print(make_lambda(1)())
print(make_lambda(2)())
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. Here `fun1` and `fun2` are known at compile time. In my case, I have the AST for `fun1`/`fun2`, which can be codegened into a valid string of python code. More over, this AST changes during execution. In my python file, I don't know what `fun1` and `fun2` look like, it's constructed during runtime, and want to execute it. Right now I interpret the AST which is slow.